# Unable to drag an item or folder in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: unity, 17.10

I am unable to drag a folder/ item in Ubuntu 17.10 with Unity. When I am trying to drag an item it is just getting selected but not moving along with the mouse. In the image below I tried to drag the audio file, but unable to do so.

[image]

This drag and drop feature worked initially, but it broke later.